# Generate data file at install time

Tags: setup.py, data-files

My python package depends on a static data file which is automatically generated from a smaller seed file using a function that is part of the package.

It makes sense to me to do this generation at the time of running `setup.py install`, is there a standard way in `setup()` to describe “run this function before installing this package's additional files” (the options in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) are all static)? If not, where should I place the call to that function?

Answer (score 2):

Best done in two steps using the `cmdclass` mechanism:

- add a custom command to generate the data file
- override `build_py` to call that before proceeding

```py
from distutils.cmd import Command

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class GenerateDataFileCommand(Command):
    description = 'generate data file'
    user_options = []

    def run(self):
        pass  # Do something here...


class InstallCommand(install):

    def run(self):
        self.run_command('generate_data_file')
        return super().run()


setup(
    cmdclass={
        'generate_data_file': GenerateDataFileCommand,
        'install': InstallCommand,
    },
    # ...
)
```

This way you can call `python setup.py generate_data_file` to generate the data file as a stand-alone step, but the usual setup procedure (`python setup.py install`) will also ensure it's called.

(However, I'd recommend including the built file in the distribution archive, so end users don't have to build it themselves – that is, override `build_py` (class `setuptools.command.build_py.build_py`) instead of install.)